# Join another table in this sql query

Tags: mysql, join

I'm using this one to get related softwares based on their keywords. Now I want to add one more condition that is in another table called `software_status` having `software_id`. I found this query on SO, so I can't understand it and can't edit it further.

```
SELECT softwares.*, count(DISTINCT similar.kid) as shared_tags
FROM softwares
INNER JOIN ( keywords_softwares AS this_software INNER JOIN keywords_softwares AS similar USING (kid) ) ON similar.sid = softwares.id
WHERE this_software.sid=:id
AND   softwares.id != this_software.sid
AND (softwares.subcategory = :subcatid or softwares.category = :catid) 
GROUP BY softwares.id
ORDER BY shared_tags DESC LIMIT 10
```

Comment: This looks like PDO syntax.

Comment: What tables are you wanting to join? Please provide layout for each.

Comment: I just want to add another condition from table called `software_status` so i can get only the softwares where `software_status.status=1`.